# Dúvida sobre $.getJSON em páginas que utilizam Templates PHP

Tags: jquery, json

Conheço e já sei como utilizar o método `$.getJSON` do jQuery retornando os dados que são retornados com PHP pelo `json_encode()`.

Acontece que, no projeto em que estou desenvolvendo, eu utilizo um [Template](http://raelcunha.com/template.php) (PHP) para melhor organização em questão de HTML e PHP. E, por exemplo, estou na index do meu site e clico em um link (que faz a função para o `$.getJSON`) que é direcionado à meusite.com.br/Igor. Nessa pasta (/Igor) existe um *index.php* do qual é o arquivo responsável por definir as variáveis e exibir o template (HTML).

Nesse caso, há como utilizar o `$.getJSON` para retornar tais dados?
Se não, como proceder nesse caso?

**Obrigado!**

Comment: Se seu `index.html` retorna HTML, o *browser* só vai obter HTML. Você teria que usar `$.get` em vez de `$.getJSON` (o `get` "adivinha" o tipo, mas se você quiser mais segurança pode passar `dataType : "html"` nos parâmetros). Mas se você quer JSON, o servidor tem que retornar JSON. Você poderia por exemplo passar um parâmetro pro seu `index.php` dizendo o que quer que seja retornado, se viável. Mas do ponto de vista do servidor, se não há nada indicando o que o *browser* quer, ele vai se comportar da forma padrão - que é retornar um HTML.

Comment: Mas, se eu for utilizar $.get("/Igor")... Ele vai "detectar" o index.php existente na pasta e carregar o mesmo?

Comment: Tanto o `$.get` quanto o `$.getJSON` fazem apenas uma requisição Ajax, mais nada. Não é diferente de você ir até a barra de endereços e digitar a URL. O mapeamento entre uma URL e um recurso no servidor (um documento estático, um template, uma imagem...) ocorre somente no servidor, o *browser* não tem nada a ver com isso.

Comment: Sim, isso eu sei, mas acho que vc não entendeu a minha pergunta. Assim como o browser detecta o index.php ao acessar uma pasta em um site o $.get detecta se a requisição se for uma pasta? (Ex.: /contato)

Comment: O *browser* não detecta nada, se você pede `/contato` ele vai pedir `/contato` pro servidor. É o servidor que vai decidir que `/contato` mapeia pra um arquivo ou pra um template. Ou seja, tanto faz se você digita na barra de URL, se você usa `$.ajax` (ou `$.get` ou `$.post`), se você faz um `curl` a partir da linha de comando... Em todos os casos, você está pedindo `/contato` pro servidor, e é ele quem decide qual a maneira certa de responder a esse pedido.

Comment: Espera! Você está dizendo que `/Igor` **redireciona** para `/index.php`? (tipo, retornando um código HTTP `30X`?)

Comment: Não, o /Igor possui um index.php do qual gera um template de um arquivo html (praticamente um require de um arquivo html)

Comment: Então continua valendo o que eu falei antes (aliás, mesmo se fosse um *redirect*, ainda continuaria valendo - pois [o Ajax funciona normalmente mesmo com um redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573589/520779)). Pode usar `$.get` sem problemas que o servidor vai saber o que fazer (i.e. recebendo um pedido pra `/Igor`, executar o PHP e retornar o resultado).

Comment: Hmmm então ok. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! De manhã farei uns testes e então retornarei aqui para falar sobre os resultados.

Comment: É, realmente funcionou! O problema é que me surgiram algumas outras dúvidas, mas aí já são para outra pergunta. Hehe. Muito obrigado pelas dicas!